# textarea issue in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, textarea

`textarea` gives an image scroll in IE... is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: IE seems to get away with pretty much everything. But i highly doubt that that is what you mean...

Comment: Do you mean you don't want a scroll bar in the textarea? Why not? It it needed if the user enters a lot of text. If you don't want the user to enter a lot of text or no text at all, then don't use a textarea.

Comment: this is bcoz there is a browser issue among ie & firefox in the appearance

Comment: How about you **exactly** explain that "issue"?

Comment: @RoToRa.. the thing is that i need to have an address field that has to be like an input field but with a height (say 100px;).. i m using textarea for this but in IE it has the scrollbar on the right whereas no such thing is there in firefox..

Comment: Why can't you use a input then?

Answer (score 0):

Add following style and check agian

```
.textarea{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  scroll:auto;
}
```

Edited Sorry this should be as follows

```
textarea{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  scroll:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
textarea {
resize: none;
}
```